# Circumcircle of a regular n-sided polygon inscribed in a regular (n+1)-sided polygon

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

(This is part of an exercise from Bjarne Stroustrup's textbook - 12.12, *Programming & Practice Using C++*. It may have been answered somewhere, so if you know where that is, provide me the link. I'd be grateful)

I'm drawing a series of regular polygons, where each vertex of the n-sided polygon lies on a side (not sharing any vertex) of the (n+1)-sided one, n >= 3 and increased by 1 each successive polygon.

(Edit: may not be true for n >= 5. That is, "there may not exist a regular n-sided polygon where each vertex lies on a side of a (n+1)-sided polygon, for n >= 5". If so, please write a rigorous proof instead. Thank you)
[image]

Let $R_n$ be the radius of the circumcircle of a  regular n-sided polygon, $(x_n, y_n)$ the co-ordinate of the circle's centre, $a_n$ the length of the polygon's side. Suppose these polygons are oriented similar to those in the illustration so that $x_n$ remains constant.

1) Does there exist a general formula (or a recursive one) to calculate the value of $R_{n+1}$ when $R_n$ is known?

2) Does there exist a formula to get $y_{n+1}$ when $y_n$ is known? Can $y_{n+1} - y_n$ be denoted only in terms of $R_n$ and/or $R_{n+1}$ and the other known constants?

[Circumcircles of regular n-sided polygons, n ranges from 3 to 8](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kQEho.jpg)

---

I've solved the first 3 cases where n = 3 and 4, but am stuck going further. While n = 3 is pretty straightforward, any further increase in n makes the equation become barely readable, and apparently doesn't seem to have any pattern. I would appreciate if you can provide a direction.

I notice that both R and y increase in smaller amount each successive term, which hints that they may converge to certain values. This one is just asking for curiosity. I know it's a bit too much to ask in one question, so you can just give directions, not necessarily the whole proof.

3) Do $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{R_n}{R_{n-1}}$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty}(y_n - y_{n-1})$ exist?

Comment: How exactly are the polygons inscribed (which sides of the inscribed polygon are tangent)?

Comment: To amplify @automaticallyGenerated's comment: For $n\geq 5$, a regular $n$-gon doesn't meet the edges of a regular $(n+1)$-gon in the manner one might expect from the term "inscribed". Note that your own pentagon looks properly-sized along the bottom, yet it is ever-so-slightly *too wide* at its left/right extremes, but also *too short* at the top; shrinking to fix the left/right will make the top gap worse, while expanding to fix the top will make the left/right worse. Your bigger polygons don't even fit along their bottoms, so it's not at all clear which incidences you wish to prioritize.

Comment: @Blue each vertex of the inscribed polygon lies on a side (not sharing any vertex) of the outer one.

Comment: @viptrongproz98: (Beyond the square in the pentagon,) That is *not possible*, as your own image shows.

Comment: @Blue (Sorry tagged the wrong person) There are gaps in the illustration, but since those are manually drawn in Photoshop, I thought that it was due to my carelessness and not that the polygons satisfying such conditions do not really exist. If the latter is true, then the problem may change from "inscribed" to "cover the most area" though. I'll make an edit and notify others.

Comment: @viptrongproz98: If you've used a "regular polygon"-type tool in Photoshop, then your image should be accurate enough to conclude that the inscription doesn't work. That said, you might consider using [GeoGebra](http://geogebra.org) to make an image with a (free) tool designed specifically for mathematical constructions.